# Правильное построение meta тэгов

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как лучше поступить.

1. Чтобы у всех страниц сайта тэги `description` и `keywords` были одинаковыми. А заголовок `<title>` для всех страниц разный.
2. Чтобы увсех страниц были разные и тэги `description` и `keywords` и заголовок `<title>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно же 2-й пункт! Почитайте что такое сниппеты в поисковых системах, как их использовать! За одно узнаете как description влияет на сниппет.